# Listar interfaces de red con VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms

Espero puedan ayudarme. Estoy intentando listar solo las interfaces de red activas con VB.NET

Tengo el siguiente código con el que voy trabajando y lo malo es que me lista mas interfaces de lo que visiblemente hay en el administrador de redes de windows.

```
        Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics         
            If netadapter.NetworkInterfaceType <> NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback Then
                cAdapter.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)
            End If
        Next
```

El código anterior lista las interfaces de red que hay en Windows, pero también añade esta interfaz **Conexion de area local*** (2 veces) y al revisar el administrador de redes de Windows, no se visualizan esas interfaces.

Alguien ya trabajo esto con anterioridad?
Como podría listar solo las interfaces de red activas que se visualizan en el administrador de redes de Windows?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: cuando haces ipconfig /all no las ves esas interfaces?

Comment: **netsh interface show interface** lista las interfaces, pero eso funciona en BATCH, me interesa cargar cada interfaz en un LISTBOX de VB.NET para que al seleccionar cada interfaz pueda manipular sus propiedades de IP.